# values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')

Tags: android, react-native

in my react native project I am not able to generate release apk (it works in debug mode), cause I get this error:

> values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the
>   given name (at 'dialogCornerRadius' with value
>   '?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius')

I know this problem can occurr when you have different compileSdkVersion as compare to your library version, but its not my case.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
}
```

As you can see all versions are 26.

I also tried to set the version to 28 (compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion and com.android.support:appcompat-v7), but I still get the error.

Answer (score -1):

In my project, i create a new module, the lib: "androidx.appcompat:appcompat" was imported by IDE, after i remove it, build work normally.

I found that, cannot use androidx libs unless using the build version larger than target 27.